# What Lost Phone finder do you use and why?

Tags: security, lost-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best lost / stolen device tracking app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/best-lost-stolen-device-tracking-app)

I've used MobileDefense, but I want to make sure I'm getting the best protection. What lost phone finders have you used, and why do you like it?

I'm not using a rooted phone, so I'm not looking for features that require root.

Comment: Your question should be a little more specific.  What about MobileDefense don't you like or what feature are you looking for?  As it is now, your question isn't much different than "What's your favorite X app?", which is really more discussion based rather than Q&A.