# Best lost / stolen device tracking app

Tags: applications, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Helping a lost phone get found](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/helping-a-lost-phone-get-found)

What is the best tracking app for a stolen or lost device? I've tried iTag but I'm thinking about switching to Prey http://preyproject.com/blog/2010/01/prey-arrives-on-mobiles-android-version-available . Looking for experiences...