# Google's location history minute by minute

Tags: google-maps, lost-phone, google-location-history

My phone was stolen. Is it possible to get the location history as realtime as possible from Google?

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18644/my-phone-was-just-stolen-an-hour-or-so-ago-are-there-any-options-for-tracking     and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/how-can-i-find-a-lost-phone-or-help-people-return-it

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy, You have to just login here with your Google account which is configured on your mobile - https://maps.google.co.in/locationhistory/b/0/

Then you can get location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The Phone Locator by Google](https://www.google.com/android/find?u=0). As they show you the pin on the map click the pin it will redirect you to a new tab, keep refreshing. the data is there.